# Rails associations has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm unable to grasp the detail understanding of following rails association.

has_many through
has_and_belongs_to_many

What this associations do and the effect on table? please help

Comment: I assume you already read the official documentation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Has_many is basically saying that one thing links to many, for example one category has many products within in. Belongs_to is basically the other way around, so a product belongs to category. They allow you to retrieve data from a table that links to the other table e.g. You could get the category title from the product table for a certain product through that link. Does that help?

Comment: a little bit but I'm asking about

   1)  has_many through
    2) has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/76825 and: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

> Rails offers two different ways to declare a many-to-many relationship
>   between models. The simpler way is to use has_and_belongs_to_many,
>   which allows you to make the association directly:
>
> ```
> class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
> end
>
> class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
> end
> ```
>
> The second way to declare a many-to-many relationship is to use
>   has_many :through. This makes the association indirectly, through a
>   join model:
>
> ```
> class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :manifests
>   has_many :parts, through: :manifests
> end
>
> class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :assembly
>   belongs_to :part
> end
>
> class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :manifests
>   has_many :assemblies, through: :manifests
> end
> ```
>
> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many
>   :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model
>   as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the
>   relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember
>   to create the joining table in the database).
>
> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks,
>   or extra attributes on the join model.

Let me highlight the most important sentence:

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Answer (score 0):

`has and belongs to many` is very simple to use, but you don't have direct access to related objects, you can only hold references to two models, and nothing else.

While `has many through` will enable you to do things like user.role and to get a list of all connected second model instances. It will also enable you to get access to data specific to the relation between first and second models.

It all depends if you need something quick and easy, like for a mockup or you want to build a long-term project. I recommend you to [check this out](https://kolosek.com/rkolosek.com/rails-associations/) for more details.